# Run Java path finder

Tags: java, eclipse, jpf

I run java path finder in eclipse and I received the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited
>   package name: java.lang

```
at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:480)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:626)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
at gov.nasa.jpf.JPFClassLoader.findClass(JPFClassLoader.java:294)
at gov.nasa.jpf.JPFClassLoader.loadClass(JPFClassLoader.java:262)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2670)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1603)
at gov.nasa.jpf.Main.main(Main.java:51)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Please provide the code, and post the full stack trace.

Comment: How did you open the project in eclipse? As a new java project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.lang](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354275/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-securityexception-prohibited-package-name)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn matter how do you open the project in eclipse. You shouldn't use "New Java Project" or "New Java Project from Existing Ant Buildfile". For more information on how to open th JPF project in eclipse, have a look [here](http://javapathfinder.sourceforge.net/JPF_and_Eclipse.html).