# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.lang

Tags: java, runtime-error

I'm a newbie at Java and I have a program that is returning the following error that I am completely unable to figure out. I googled and everything. Could you guys help me?

```
package java.lang;
public class S1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i=1;i<=1000;i++)
        {
            String str = "1" +i;
        }
    }
}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.lang
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

I am using Eclipse, and am working with the package `java.lang` in the file `S1.java`.

Comment: Ok thanks, so what should I change my package name to?

Comment: You should create your own package! and put your class inside. Once the package is created, you just use its name.

Comment: and then import java.lang?

Comment: The java.lang is the default package. You do not need to import it.

Comment: @user2529024 `java.lang` is always imported implicitly by default, so no, you don't have to!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't place new content into the `java.lang` package. It's reserved by the language because that's where the core Java content already resides. In fact, everything within the `java.lang` package is implicitly imported by default, in any piece of Java code.

It contains "classes that are fundamental to the design of the Java programming language." (from [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/package-summary.html)). Since user-defined classes cannot, by definition, be critical to the design of the language, you are forbidden from putting content there. Allowing users to put code within the `java.lang` package would also be a problem because that would expose any package-domain content defined there to the user.

Just change your package name (to virtually anything else), and you'll be good to go. By convention, package names are usually lowercase, but you can make it whatever makes sense for your project. See the [tutorial on packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html) for more.

Comment: Ok, I don't have a package name anymore (removed it) but the application isn't running. It's saying [terminated] S1 (2) [Java Application].

Comment: +1... @user2529024 you are not doing nothing with it, if you want to print in console use, System.out.println(str) after the loop , and declare `String str` out of for scope

Answer (score 3):

Right click on your package click reflactor and then rename it..... Because you used internal variable.. See the image below..

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[`java.lang`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/package-summary.html) is system package from jvm which is implicitly imported to java source so its already taken you can't have same package name

Answer (score 1):

You package name coincides with the "internal" package provided in java.

Answer (score 1):

User code is never allowed to put classes into one of the standard Java packages. That way, user code cannot access any package-private classes/methods/fields in the Java implementation. Some of those package-private objects allow access to JVM internals.

@credit Chris Jester-Young

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same error with having "Java" inside the package name. I assume you already have an answer to this but these internal package errors can be a pain to figure out.

Just change your package name and you should be Gucci.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you use `package` instead of `import` in your code:

```
// package java.lang; <-- this is wrong! You don't need it 

public class S1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i=1;i<=1000;i++)
        {
            String str = "1" +i;
        }
    }
}
```

Also **DON'T** put your code in a folder call *java* and try to execute it from outside, you will get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This is a java security issue, It will fix by changing the package name.

Comment: Please see [No Thanks, Damn It!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it)